# How can I set a previous state/storage trie when running ethereumjs-vs runCode?

Tags: evm, ethereumjs

I am trying to call runCode on an ethereumjs VM with the contract code, the necessary data (method specifier + params; encoded) and the contract storage trie I got from a previous call on runCode which called the constructor and initialized the contract. 
Unfortunately I cannot manage to run the VM with runCode such that the code is run and the storage trie I pass to the VM is updated.